# iPadOS 13.4 trackpad IUIPointerInteractionDelegate method GetStyleForRegion not being called

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, trackpad, ipados13, uipointerinteraction

I am working on an iPadOS 13.4 app that works with trackpad input. I have gotten a lot of things working, like [two-finger scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61845476/getting-a-custom-uiview-to-respond-to-a-two-finger-trackpad-scroll-gesture-or-m), right-click (two-finger or control-click), pinch-to-zoom, etc. I have another control that works great with the trackpad but it is a custom text control, so I need to change the round cursor from a circle to an I-beam using the [UIPointerInteraction APIs.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/pointer_interactions)

I modified an Apple-provided [Swift sample code project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/pointer_interactions/integrating_pointer_interactions_into_your_ipad_app) and got an I-beam to appear over a view so I know what to do if the system will call my **styleFor: region** method, but **it just won't call it**. The Xamarin APIs are not yet documented for this; the best is the Assembly Browser and the API diffs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/api-changes/ios-13-14-1-13-16-0) that mention the method signatures. I am on Xamarin.iOS 13.16.1.

```
public class MyClass: UIView, IUIPointerInteractionDelegate {

    ...

    initalization_code() {
        ...
        UIPointerInteraction interaction = new UIPointerInteraction(this);
        this.AddInteraction(interaction);
    }

    public UIPointerStyle GetStyleForRegion(UIPointerInteraction interaction, UIPointerRegion region) {
        // this code is never called
        const float HEIGHT = 30f;
        return UIPointerStyle.Create(UIPointerShape.CreateBeam((nfloat)HEIGHT, UIAxis.Vertical), UIAxis.Vertical);
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to get iOS to call into my C# code for GetStyleForRegion?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this Export annotation did the job:

```
[Export("pointerInteraction:styleForRegion:")]
public UIPointerStyle GetStyleForRegion(UIPointerInteraction interaction, UIPointerRegion region) {
    // this code gets called now!
    const float HEIGHT = 30f;
    return UIPointerStyle.Create(UIPointerShape.CreateBeam((nfloat)HEIGHT, UIAxis.Vertical), UIAxis.Vertical);
}
```

Now the method is called.